# Alternate Perforce Client?

Tags: user-interface, client, perforce, p4win

Can recommend a P4Win-like alternative for Perforce, hopefully that supports shelving and may be open source?  Needn't be cross platform, just Windows would be fine.

I'm asking as I'm not a fan of the new P4V interface, and I found P4Win a lot more intuitive, easier to use, and much more stream lined.

I haven't found much in my Google searching, but I'm hoping this nexus of programmers might know of a hidden jewel out there. :)

Comment: P4Win hasn't stopped working, has it?

Comment: I too was reluctant to switch from P4Win to P4V.  I occasionally tried it during my first couple years of Perforce use, but always went back to P4Win.  However, when I learned development on P4Win was going to stop, I bit the bullet and forced myself to use P4V.  I quickly learned that it's better than P4Win.  Have you really given it a chance?  By that I mean use it exclusively for a couple weeks and don't immediately open up P4Win when you can't figure out how to do something.  Figure it out.  I bet you'll come to like it.  Plus, I don't think there are any other graphical Perforce clients.

Comment: @Tim: No, it hasn't.  That said, features like shelving aren't available and won't be ported to P4Win.

Comment: P4Win feels much more responsive than P4V; I guess partly because it uses native widgets. It's a shame there's no P4Win alternative on Windows - OS X has P4Cocoa, which feels very similar in style to P4Win.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't really an answer, but I don't have enough rep to comment on the original post. If your primary concern is support for shelving, you can still use shelve/unshelve through the command line. You could probably even hook it into to P4Win UI using a simple Python (or your language of choice) script that's set up as an external tool that runs on changelists.